# UIWebView: Width of table affects text size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've encountered a rather strange bug in UIWebView. If I create a table and on of the `<td>`:s are too long (longer than the width of the screen, I guess), the font size gets enlarged!

Here is an example app I threw together to demonstrate this.

This piece of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>         
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table
            td
            {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>                  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mi ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Produces this result:

[image: iPhone Table strangeness]

The top table gets enlarged! The ONLY thing that's different is that the first line is longer in the top table. This makes the font size for the whole table bigger!

I've tried using `<nobr>` instead of CSS and it gives the same result. Setting the font size with inline styles does not work either.

I also get the same result if I set the width of a `<td>` to a size larger than the screen, so it seems like there is some auto sizeing that is the problem.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?!

**UPDATE**

Here is my project if you want to try it out for yourself:
http://cl.ly/2B3r1F2C3I0C2D1S2X3s

**UPDATE 2**

I forgot to mention that I have tried setting font sizes throigh CSS. Both in the `<style>` and inline and even through JavaScript, after the page has loaded loke so:

.

```
td
{
    font-size: 18px;
}

<td style="font-size: 18px;">

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].style.fontSize = '18px';
}
```

This has no effect.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using native UITableViews for this?

Comment: It is for some data charts that are created through a wysiwyg web admin tool, so UIWebView is required.

Comment: This is also happening in normal Safari and even in Chrome on iPhone 5s. It can even be reproduced in XCode simulator. It seems to be model dependent: In XCode it happens in iPhone 5s, 6, 6 Plus and 6s but NOT in iPhone 6s Plus (all tested in XCode simulator with iOS 9.0). The JS hack of @Lee Gary did not work in my tests, neither on a real 5s nor in the simulations.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(**var** i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontSize = '18px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any font sizes being specified. I would try manually setting the font sizes with CSS or HTML.